# JS Toggle show only clicked one and hide all others

Tags: javascript, toggle

I just found this helpful JS Toggle..
Is it possible to modify this one? I just want to show the actual selected one and hide all others..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(control){
var elem = document.getElementById(control);

if(elem.style.display == "none"){
    elem.style.display = "block";
}else{
    elem.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>


<a href="javascript:toggle('test')"> link</a>
<br /><div id="test" style="display: none">text</div>
```

Comment: Yes, of course it is. But what HTML should it act upon? Are you using classes to identify elements, or some other property? Show us your (relevant) code: help us to help you.

Comment: The HTML is generated by PHP.. The Strukture is like that:
<select name="form" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="javascript:toggle('id..')">Some Text</option>
</select>

And then divs are generated <div id="id.." style =""display:none"> some text</div>

Was that helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<script>
function show(idToShow, classToHide) {
    var classList = document.querySelectorAll('.'+classToHide);
    var thisElem  = document.getElementById(idToShow);
    var wasShown  = (thisElem.style.display == "block");

    var i = -1;
    while (node=classList[++i]) {
        node.style.display ="none";
    };

    if(!wasShown){
        thisElem.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="show('a','all');">A
        <div class="all" id="a" style="display:none">The stuff to show</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="show('b','all');">B
        <div class="all" id="b" style="display:none">The stuff to show</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="show('c','all');">C
        <div class="all" id="c" style="display:none">The stuff to show</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It was a fight to get IE 8 support, `document.getElementsByClassName` was not supported in that version. It seems that `document.querySelectorAll` *does* work in IE 8, but not in quirks mode. Sample code fixed to use this and engage standard mode.

Note: My first quick hack of this used a `for` loop rather than the while:

```
    for (var i=0;i<classList.length;i++) {
        classList[i].style.display ="none";
    };
```

Bonus points if you can spot when this will fail (hover mouse to see answer):

> if there's an element in the list with the id `length` (in which case `classList.length` will refer to that element, not the length of the NodeList.)

Comment: Hey Kim SJ! Thanks for the answer. unfortunately the code is not working. I also replaced the for loop.. There must be something wrong :/

Comment: @user3414925 If you'd like, can you put your code somewhere (e.g. jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com) and I'll have a look at it. Have you checked the console [(instructions for chrome here, for example)](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to see if it's explaining things for you?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with IE8... Works fine in Chrome.. 
Alert in IE8 is like: "Object is not supporting the method / value..." (orig: german) any ideas?

Comment: [Checking caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName) shows that `getElementsByClassName` was not supported by IE8. If total cross-browser support is required, you might consider using jqueryUI (a sledgehammer, but one with the heavy lifting done for you)

Comment: Hmm... document.querySelectorAll('.all') looks like it solves your IE8 problem... solution edited. :-)

Comment: Sorry, same problem..  document.querySelectorAll is not supported as well. I am not allowed to install new UI's like jQuery. Maybe I will take another solution to solve this problem. If u have another idea to fix the problem please let me know in this post. Thank you for your help Kim!

Comment: Well well, you're right... looks like 3% of users are s.o.l. on this... and caniuse.com seems to be wrong! I guess you'll have to create the list yourself somehow, if you really want to support IE8. Or you could just have a global for "divToHide" which you update whenever you open one. And incidentally, this means that `getElementsByClassName` does have wider browser support than `querySelectorAll`, which is what I originally thought... I'll change my solution back. :-)

Comment: Aaah! This is a quirks mode thing... [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404362/queryselectorall-alternative-for-ie) explains.