# IE8 returns 'Object expected' [].slice.call

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Im newbie in js, this code works good on all browser except  li elements (tabs).

```js
 (function() {

   [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs')).forEach(function(el) {
     new CBPFWTabs(el);
   });

 })();
```

Any help?

Comment: upd: change it  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs')) to  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tabs"))
still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 partially supports `querySelectorAll()`, http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

read this too :[querySelectorAll alternative for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404362/queryselectorall-alternative-for-ie)

Comment: Isnt it problem with [].slice.call ? It says error on "character 3"