# IE7 Queryselector not finding elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

```js
if (!document.querySelectorAll)
  document.querySelectorAll = function(selector) {
    var head = document.documentElement.firstChild;
    var styleTag = document.createElement("STYLE");
    head.appendChild(styleTag);
    document.__qsResult = [];

    styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector+"{x:expression(document.__qsResult.push(this))}";
    window.scrollBy(0, 0);
    head.removeChild(styleTag);

    var result = [];
    for (var i in document.__qsResult)
      result.push(document.__qsResult[i]);
    return result;
  }

 var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
 var descriptionTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".descriptionTab");
 var hireTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".hireTab");
 var salesTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".salesTab");
 var lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");



console.log(tabs.length);
console.log(hireTabs.length);
console.log(salesTabs.length);
console.log(descriptionTabs.length);
console.log(lazyImages.length);
```

```html
<img class="imageThumbs lazy" src="">
<img class="imageThumbs lazy" src="">
<img class="imageThumbs lazy" src="">
<img class="imageThumbs" src="">

<div class="tabContainer">
     <div class="descriptionTab tab">Description</div>
     <div class="hireTab tab">HireTab</div>
     <div class="salesTab tab">SalesTab</div>
</div>
```

I have a weird problem with IE, document mode 7.

The weirdest thing about it is that my functions work fine in document modes 5 and 8.

Certain elements are not being found. When I check the browser developers tools they are in there, in the HTML doc.

I can't see why those ones are incorrect in this particular version of IE and all others work fine.

Hopefully someone has an idea. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is a seperate script soley for earlier versions of IE. I am using getElementsByClassName in the other script.

The script tag is at the bottom of the HTML page.

It works everywhere else except IE7.

EDIT: Change code to be a snippet.

EDIT: I have pinpointed the issue by stepping through.

```
styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector+"{x:expression(document.__qsResult.push(this))}";
```

This line seems to work on some elements and not others, so they are not getting pushed. As far as I can see there is not difference between

```
var descriptionTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".descriptionTab");
```

Which works and

```
var hireTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".hireTab");
```

Which doesn't.

FinalEdit(I give up): The Results seems to differ depending on what order the queryselectors are in.

Comment: If all you need to do is match tags, ids and class names, I would opt for using getElementById(), getElementsByClassName() and getElementsByTagName() 
 over a CSS hack that only works on specific instances of IE. Imho, the only reason to use this hack is when you need complex CSS selectors.

Comment: can you confirm that you are calling all this when dom is ready?

Comment: Would be really easy to tell an IE7 user to use a modern browser. So many quirks in those older versions. Used to be whole sites dedicated to *"IE Hacks"*

Comment: This is a seperate script soley for earlier versions of IE. I am using getElementsByClassName in the other script.

Comment: Won't it be easier then to just add id's to the parent elements and filter their childNodes list so it works on all browsers? Then the browser can at least optimize those childNode loops. Compared to the CSS expressions that need to be parsed, and then will loop over the DOM anyway to find the correct elements. It just comes across as alot of extra issues ( seperate script for IE, safety issues due to CSS expressions using eval, incompatibilities between IE versions, not all CSS selectors being available in IE ) just to be able to use querySelector() syntax.

Comment: Not really because there will be a different amount of elements on every page.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (including the HTML), ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). For instance, no `.tab` elements are being found. Great! So you should be able to create an MCVE with one `.tab` element.

Comment: I added a snippet, but because the issue I am having is in IE7. The problem will not be replicated in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found a solution on Github.

https://gist.github.com/Fusselwurm/4673695

```
(function () {
    var
        style = document.createStyleSheet(),
        select = function (selector, maxCount) {
            var
                all = document.all,
                l = all.length,
                i,
                resultSet = [];

            style.addRule(selector, "foo:bar");
            for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                if (all[i].currentStyle.foo === "bar") {
                    resultSet.push(all[i]);
                    if (resultSet.length > maxCount) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            style.removeRule(0);
            return resultSet;

        };

    //  be rly sure not to destroy a thing!
    if (document.querySelectorAll || document.querySelector) {
        return;
    }

    document.querySelectorAll = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, Infinity);
    };
    document.querySelector = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, 1)[0] || null;
    };
}());
```

This works in all the earlier IE versions. I just replaced the polyfill I was using previously.

Answer (score -1):

It's not supported, https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

You can use alternatives like `findElementById` or `findElementByClassName`

Comment: That is why I have the function at the top as a polyfill. if (!document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: Maybe this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404362/queryselectorall-alternative-for-ie

Comment: The query selector is working though. If you can see in my code on some of the console logs it is returning the correct amount.

Comment: @Shemiroth, Can you please describe in detail or with example. what do you mean by, 'Results seems to differ depending on what order the queryselectors are in.' I also want to confirm with you that which actual version of IE you are trying to make a test with? If it is IE 11 than I suggest you to make a test with actual IE 7. Document mode will not give an accurate results in many conditions.